# How to make golang signal handler working on windows

Tags: go

The following test program is working fine on my linux machine, but it is not working on my windows machine

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    detectShutdown()
    fmt.Println("Running")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}

func detectShutdown() {
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGINT)
    go func() {
        sig := <-sigChan
        fmt.Printf("Signal [%s] detected\n", sig)
        os.Exit(1)
    }()
}
```

Output on linux

```
Running
^CSignal [interrupt] detected
```

Output on Windows

```
Running
```

Anyone has idea on how to make it works on Windows? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Windows does not have POSIX (Unix) signals as a form of supported IPC. Handling `Ctrl-C` (and `Ctrl-Break`) keyboard combinations in console applications is done completely different on Windows than it is done in programs running attached to Unix-compatible terminals and terminal emulators.

Since some time Go has gained support in `os/signal` for Windows in the form of a special signal `os.Interrupt`, which, on POSIX-compatible systems is an alias for `os.SIGINT` (and is processed in the usual way), and on Windows it does not stand for any signal (for their lack thereof) but is emulated when the user presses the keyboard combinations mentioned above.

I advise you to actually read the docs of the `os/signal` package—especially its section called "Windows". Doing this up-front would have saved you and me spending time asking and answering a question about a non-problem.